# When installing from the bootable USB, I get an error on my monitor (Monitor Out of Range)

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, display

I know this question may seem similar to [When I turn the monitor on, I get an “input out of range”, how do I fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593457/when-i-turn-the-monitor-on-i-get-an-input-out-of-range-how-do-i-fix-this), but it certainly isn't. My question, although causing the same error, happens when I'm trying to install ubuntu.
So I've made my computer first boot from the USB, and this works - after it's booted a little bit, it comes up with a black screen, with text which is basically some options. I select the option to install Ubuntu.
My monitor turns black, but I can tell that it's still on. After a few seconds, I get told that my monitor is out of range (or something along these lines - I can't remember exactly).
The monitor I'm using is a BenQ EW2440, and this is what's telling me the error, as it's displayed in the format which my monitor usually tells me stuff.
So, **how can I get past this black screen?**

Comment: Some assistance may be found on this blog post: https://blog.siliconforks.com/2010/05/07/monitor-out-of-range-installing-ubuntu-lucid-lynx/